# JS - nested for loops - compare 2 arrays by key, return 4 new arrays, matches & unmatches from each

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

Made a demo for the question -

The arrays -

```
const arr1 = [
  {
    key: "daniel|21",
    name: "daniel",
    age: 21,
    city: "NYC"
  },
  {
    key: "kosta|28",
    name: "kosta",
    age: 28,
    city: "NYC"
  }
];

const arr2 = [
  {
    key: "daniel|21",
    name: "daniel",
    age: 21,
    city: "TLV"
  },
  {
    key: "simon|24",
    name: "simon",
    age: 24,
    city: "NYC"
  },
  {
    key: "david|22",
    name: "david",
    age: 22,
    city: "NYC"
  }
];
```

Empty arrays for assigning -

```
let arr1Match = [];
let arr1Unmatch = [];

let arr2Match = [];
let arr2Unmatch = [];
```

For loop -

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
for (let j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
    const arr1Key = arr1[i].key;
    const arr2Key = arr2[j].key;

    if (arr1Key === arr2Key) {
        arr1Match.push(arr1[i])
        arr2Match.push(arr2[i])
    } else {
        arr1Unmatch.push(arr1[i])
        arr2Unmatch.push(arr2[i])
    }
}
```

}

What I'm outputing -

```
console.log(arr1Match);
console.log(arr1Unmatch);

console.log(arr2Match);
console.log(arr2Unmatch);
```

Output -

arr1Match: `[{ "key": "daniel|21", "name": "daniel", "age": 21, "city": "NYC" }]`

arr1Unmatch: `[{ "key": "daniel|21", "name": "daniel", "age": 21, "city": "NYC" }, { "key": "daniel|21", "name": "daniel", "age": 21, "city": "NYC" }, { "key": "kosta|28", "name": "kosta", "age": 28, "city": "NYC" }, { "key": "kosta|28", "name": "kosta", "age": 28, "city": "NYC" }, { "key": "kosta|28", "name": "kosta", "age": 28, "city": "NYC" }]`

arr2Match:  `[{ "key": "daniel|21", "name": "daniel", "age": 21, "city": "TLV" }]`

arr2Unmatch: `[{ "key": "daniel|21", "name": "daniel", "age": 21, "city": "TLV" }, { "key": "daniel|21", "name": "daniel", "age": 21, "city": "TLV" }, { "key": "simon|24", "name": "simon", "age": 24, "city": "NYC" }, { "key": "simon|24", "name": "simon", "age": 24, "city": "NYC" }, { "key": "simon|24", "name": "simon", "age": 24, "city": "NYC" }]`

The desired output -

arr1Match: `[{ "key": "daniel|21", "name": "daniel", "age": 21, "city": "NYC" }]`

arr1Unmatch: `[{ "key": "kosta|28", "name": "kosta", "age": 28, "city": "NYC" }]`

arr2Match: `[{ "key": "daniel|21", "name": "daniel", "age": 21, "city": "TLV" }]`

arr2Unmatch: `[{ "key": "simon|24", "name": "simon", "age": 24, "city": "NYC" }, { "key": "david|22", "name": "david", "age": 22, "city": "NYC" }]`

I need the loops to go through all values in the arrays and return all the matches and unmatches from each.
And I need to assing property from `arr2` to `arr1` if there is a match

Comment: @ikhvjs My bad I'll edit I need nested for loops

Comment: @pilchard I was horrobly wrong, edited the question
I need to run all over arr2 for each arr1 element

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure I understand your question, is this the result you want?

```js
const arr1 = [{
    key: "daniel|21",
    name: "daniel",
    age: 21,
    city: "NYC"
  },
  {
    key: "kosta|28",
    name: "kosta",
    age: 28,
    city: "NYC"
  }
];

const arr2 = [{
    key: "daniel|21",
    name: "daniel",
    age: 21,
    city: "TLV"
  },
  {
    key: "simon|24",
    name: "simon",
    age: 24,
    city: "NYC"
  },
  {
    key: "david|22",
    name: "david",
    age: 22,
    city: "NYC"
  }
];

const arr1Keys = arr1.map(a => a.key);
const arr2Keys = arr2.map(a => a.key);
const keys = [...arr1Keys, ...arr2Keys];
const repeat = keys.filter((o, i) => keys.indexOf(o) !== i);
const unique = [...new Set(keys)].filter(o => !repeat.includes(o));

const arr1Match = arr1.filter(a => repeat.includes(a.key));
const arr1Unmatch = arr1.filter(a => unique.includes(a.key));
const arr2Match = arr2.filter(a => repeat.includes(a.key));
const arr2Unmatch = arr2.filter(a => unique.includes(a.key));
const arr1Match2 = arr1Match.map(a1 => {
  let obj = arr2Match.find(a2 => a2.key == a1.key);
  return {...obj, city: obj.city}
});
const arr1Match3 = arr1Match.map(a1 => arr2Match.find(a2 => a2.key == a1.key));

console.log('arr1Match before', JSON.stringify(arr1Match));
console.log('arr1Match overwrite city', JSON.stringify(arr1Match2));
console.log('arr1Match overwrite all', JSON.stringify(arr1Match3));
console.log('arr1Unmatch', JSON.stringify(arr1Unmatch));
console.log('arr2Match', JSON.stringify(arr2Match));
console.log('arr2Unmatch', JSON.stringify(arr2Unmatch));
```

Comment: I can't use your way. I need to assing properties from arr2 to arr1 when there is a match

Comment: @heyheyhey What are assing properties from arr2 to arr1 when there is a match, can you be more specific about that ?

Comment: if: `{
    key: "daniel|21",
    name: "daniel",
    age: 21,
    city: "NYC"
  }` is equal to: `{
    key: "daniel|21",
    name: "daniel",
    age: 21,
    city: "TLV"
  }`

I'll need to assing a property from `arr2` to `arr1` - for the example let's say that the `city` in `arr1` should be `TLV` in output. In the example I'm changing an existing value but like that you can understand the question as good as possible

Comment: @heyheyhey oh so you mean that after the matching is complete, do you need to replace the object properties in arr1 with the object properties of the same key in arr2?

Comment: Yeah, if match assing from `arr2` to `arr1` a value by demand.

Comment: @heyheyhey hi I adjusted the code, you can look at it again, it contains the code to replace one of the attributes and replace all the attributes

Answer (score 1):

Approach to find *common* objects and update them.

```js
const
    update = (a, b) => {
        const
            fn = o => o.key,
            references = Object.fromEntries(a.map(o => [fn(o), o]));

        b.forEach(o => {
            const target = references[fn(o)];
            if (target) Object.assign(target, o);
        });
    }
    array1 = [{ key: "daniel|21", name: "daniel", age: 21, city: "NYC" }, { key: "kosta|28", name: "kosta", age: 28, city: "NYC" }],
    array2 = [{ key: "daniel|21", name: "daniel", age: 21, city: "TLV" }, { key: "simon|24", name: "simon", age: 24, city: "NYC" }, { key: "david|22", name: "david", age: 22, city: "NYC" }];

update(array1, array2);

console.log(array1); // inclusive the one with updates!
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You could get the common keys and take the partition of each array.

```js
const
    match = (a, b, fn) => {
        const 
            getCommon = (a, b) => {
                const c = {};
                a.forEach(o => c[fn(o)] = false);
                b.forEach(o => c[fn(o)] = fn(o) in c);
                return c;
            };
            common = getCommon(a, b, fn),
            getParts = (a, c) => a.reduce((r, o) => (r[+!common[fn(o)]].push(o), r), [[], []]);
            
        return [
            getParts(a, common),
            getParts(b, common)
        ];
    }
    array1 = [{ key: "daniel|21", name: "daniel", age: 21, city: "NYC" }, { key: "kosta|28", name: "kosta", age: 28, city: "NYC" }],
    array2 = [{ key: "daniel|21", name: "daniel", age: 21, city: "TLV" }, { key: "simon|24", name: "simon", age: 24, city: "NYC" }, { key: "david|22", name: "david", age: 22, city: "NYC" }],
    [
        [arr1Match, arr1Unmatch],
        [arr2Match, arr2Unmatch]
    ] = match(array1, array2, o => o.key);

console.log(arr1Match);
console.log(arr1Unmatch);

console.log(arr2Match);
console.log(arr2Unmatch);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I need to get the matches & unmatches in diffrent arrays

Comment: Sorry I edited the question now

Comment: @heyheyhey, what is wrong?

Comment: I need to assing a property from `arr2` to `arr1` if there is a match for the example let's say -

if: `{ key: "daniel|21", name: "daniel", age: 21, city: "NYC"}` is equal to: `{ key: "daniel|21", name: "daniel", age: 21, city: "TLV"}` I'll need to assing a property from arr2 to arr1 - for the example let's say that the city in arr1 should be TLV in output. In the example I'm changing an existing value but like that you can understand the question as good as possible

Comment: what is the result of it? what property?

Comment: Sorry.
I would like the output to look like that -

arr1Match: `[{ "key": "daniel|21", "name": "daniel", "age": 21, "city": "TLV" }]`

arr1Unmatch: `[{ "key": "kosta|28", "name": "kosta", "age": 28, "city": "NYC" }]`

arr2Match: `[{ "key": "daniel|21", "name": "daniel", "age": 21, "city": "TLV" }]`

arr2Unmatch: `[{ "key": "simon|24", "name": "simon", "age": 24, "city": "NYC" }, { "key": "david|22", "name": "david", "age": 22, "city": "NYC" }]`

Changed the `arr1match` `city` to `TLV`

Comment: what for do you need the complete lising of matched and unmatched items, if you want to overwithe the item/s? of array1?

Comment: On the real arrays in my project I'm going to assing a property from arr2 to arr1 when they match for future calc
For the example I made it an overwrite

Comment: do you really need only the finding of common objects and the change in common object with newer properties?

Comment: yes that's what I need